# How to create rotating log file with Laravel and Monlog

Tags: php, laravel-4, monolog

I'm trying to create my own rotating log file in Laravel using Monolog, however, the file rotation is not working and I don't know why.

I've created an artisan command that runs once per day, and keeps a log of it's activity. I want old versions of this file to be deleted after 2 days.  In other words only the log of today's run, as well as yesterday's run should exist.

At the beginning of my artisan command, I have the following code:

```
$log = new Logger('MyCustomLog');
$log->pushHandler(new RotatingFileHandler(storage_path().'/logs/mycustomlog.log'), 2);
```

Then, throughout the command, I log information to it:

```
$log->addInfo('Info to log');
```

It seemed pretty straightforward to me, but it's simply not working.  The log files are being generated correctly, but they are never getting deleted.  I see the following in my `app/storage/logs` folder:

```
mycustomlog-2015-01-30.log
mycustomlog-2015-01-31.log
mycustomlog-2015-02-01.log
mycustomlog-2015-02-02.log
mycustomlog-2015-02-03.log
```

I would expect to see only the last 2 files. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Thanks @lukasgeiter. Any idea why it's not working for me in Laravel 4 though? It seems like it's not even a Laravel issue doesn't it? I'm not really using Laravel's code here, I'm using the underlying Monolog library directly...I think.

Comment: You could try passing `2` to the constructor of `RotatingFileHandler` instead of `pushHandler` which doesn't even have a second argument ;)

Comment: Ha! Thank you, I'm sure that is definitely the problem. Didn't even notice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of your bracket did get a bit out of place. You have to pass the number of log files to the constructor of `RotatingFileHandler` and not as second argument to `pushHandler()`:

```
$log->pushHandler(new RotatingFileHandler(storage_path().'/logs/mycustomlog.log', 2));
//                                                                                ^
```