# How to configure log retention policy on Laravel 5?

Tags: php, logging, laravel-5, monolog

I have noticed that on a clean L5 setup, log files are grouped daily and maintained until 4 days ago (total 5 files) then the oldest is erased and the today's created.

Where do I set up /configure how many days to keep before erase ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do some custom logging and have the following in AppService Provider to do something else:

```
$monolog = Log::getMonolog();                                                             
$monolog->pushProcessor(new IntrospectionProcessor());
```

From here, it looks like you would add a new RotatingFileHandler (from the Monolog package) rather than using pushProcessor() like I do:

[How to create rotating log file with Laravel and Monlog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28315352/how-to-create-rotating-log-file-with-laravel-and-monlog)

```
$monolog->pushHandler(new RotatingFileHandler(storage_path().'/logs/mycustomlog.log'), 2);
```

Here you'd need to do something else with the log path/name, but the magic 2 is the retention days.

So this is a prod what could be the right direction, but you're going to have to fiddle a bit with this to get what you want:

https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/blob/master/src/Monolog/Handler/RotatingFileHandler.php

Later edit:

Just looked through Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/ConfigureLogging and found a setting for:

```
$app->make('config')->get('app.log_max_files', 5).
```

So just set log_max_files in config/app.php and that should do it. Which is just a bit easier :)

Comment: Well a bit tricky solution compared to what usually (and easly) Laravel offers. I ll try it

Comment: @koalaok - indeed it is! Just looked through Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/ConfigureLogging and found a setting for  $app->make('config')->get('app.log_max_files', 5). So just set log_max_files in config/app.php and that should do it. Which is just a bit easier :)

Comment: Gotcha! you should have placed this as answer. In order for me to accept it. Or integrate your previous answer.